# Why do I get a time one hour later using Atlantic Standard Time for St. Martin?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, cultureinfo

Ok - So right now for me it is 5:16pm Eastern.  It's also 5:16pm in St. Martin.  St. Martin is in the "Atlantic Standard Time" Zone.

When I use This value as a time zone, I get 6:16pm.  I'm using the list linked below - any ideas why this isn't working?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx

Comment: Not sure if that's what's getting you but we are currently in Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: How are you using it exactly? Please post your code.

Comment: Nice place.  Does anybody there ever actually care that the clock is off by one hour?  They don't use daylight savings, unlike other places in AST like Canada.  DST observance and transitions are local political decisions.  If the mayor doesn't like it then it doesn't happen.  Only a local machine or a paid web service knows this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most (but not all) locations in the North American Eastern Time zone are subject to daylight saving time.   For example, New York, Miami, or Washington D.C.  In these locations, the standard offset is UTC-5, which is used during the winter months, and the daylight offset is UTC-4, which is used during the summer months when daylight saving time is in effect.

Saint Martin, while in the Atlantic Time zone, does not use daylight saving time.  It always follows Atlantic Standard Time, which uses an offset of UTC-4.  [Reference Here.](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/marigot)

Note that some of the other locations in the Atlantic time zone, such as Bermuda and Nova Scotia, *do* use daylight saving time, and would have an offset of UTC-3 when daylight saving time is in effect.

Also, since you said you were using Windows time zones with the `TimeZoneInfo` class, you should be aware that the time zone having the ID of `"Atlantic Standard Time"`, and having a display name of `"(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)"`,  *does* use daylight saving time.

For Saint Martin, you should instead use `"SA Western Standard Time"`, which has a display name of `"(UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan"`, and is fixed to UTC-4.  This is the correct mapping for Marigot, Saint Martin (`America/Marigot`), as documented in [the Unicode CLDR Windows time zone mappings](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

Answer (score 0):

You're rigth it's (GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada) but you have to disable or enable daylight saving time. That's why you're getting a different value.